# How to pass a checked radio button to an other activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, radio-button

For an android app I have a RadioGroup with three RadioButtons(rb1,rb2,rb3) in my MainActivity. Each RadioButton leads to an other activity(Activity1, Activity2, Activity3). From any of these three activities the user can now go to a SettingActivity via an Actionbar. The SettingActivity has the same RadioGroup as in my MainActivity. That's how far I am.

Now the problem:
In my SettingActivity I don't want the RadioGroup to be unchecked by default. Instead I want to have checked by default the RadioButton which the user chose earlier in the MainActivity. Is there a way to do this without having to create multiple setting activities with a different default button in each?

My MainActivity:

```
btnContinue.setOnClickListener {
            if (rb1.isChecked){
                    val intent = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            else if (rb2.isChecked){
                    val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            else if (rb3.isChecked){
                    val intent = Intent(this, Activity3::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

My Activity1,2,3:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId

    if (id == R.id.settings) {
        val intent = Intent(this,SettingActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent) }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

My SettingActivity:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener {
        if (rb1.isChecked){
                val intent = Intent(this, Activity1::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        else if (rb2.isChecked){
                val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

        else if (rb3.isChecked){
                val intent = Intent(this, Activity3::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```

Comment: consider using a single activity with different fragments

Comment: Thanks! Have never used fragments so far, gonna inform myself about it now!

Comment: Use `SharedPreference` to save the state of selected button in main activity and then check the bottom accordingly in settings activity

Comment: Oh thank you! Next thing I'm going to inform myself about!

Comment: @Vadim Added the solution and little bit improved your current code

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Thanks so much for this detailed answer! This made my day!!

Comment: No problem, have fun. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,  we create a 'generic' function that starts an activity. This will remove the redundant code.

```
private fun startActivity(activity: Class<*>, radioButtonId: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, activity)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    intent.putExtra("checkedRadioButtonID", radioButtonId)
    startActivity(intent)
}



btnContinue.setOnClickListener {
    when {
          rb1.isChecked -> startActivity(Activity1::class.java, 1)
          rb2.isChecked -> startActivity(Activity2::class.java, 2)
          rb3.isChecked -> startActivity(Activity3::class.java, 3)
          else -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
      }
  }
```

Now in your three activities, you sent an intent exta to each of your activity, how? Look at the code how we started the activities. We putting `intent.putExtra()`, so we can forward data to each activity. Since each activity has a data, which is the radio button ID, we can forward this data to the settings activity.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
   menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu)
   return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val id = item.itemId

    if (id == R.id.settings) {
        val buttonId = intent.extras?.getInt("checkedRadioButtonID") //This is where we get the radio button ID in the different activity
       val intent = Intent(this,SettingActivity::class.java)
       intent.putExtra("forwardedRadioButtonId", buttonId)
       startActivity(intent)
   }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

**For settings activity**

Now we get the radio button ID forwarded from MainActivity -> Activity1/2/3 -> SettingActivity

```
val buttonId = intent.extras?.getInt("forwardedRadioButtonId")

when (buttonId) {
  1 -> rb1.isChecked = true
  2 -> rb2.isChecked = true
  3 -> rb3.isChcked = true
}
```

Finally, only the radio button will be checked which was originally checked in the `MainActivity`.